# Question about rules of higher order derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

[image]

I am doing a question from LADR by Sheldon Axler and came across this solution for a particular question. I am just confused about how one can just pull out the (j-k)th derivative from the kth derivative of $x^k$ (this is boxed in red). I do not understand how we can apply exponent rules to derivatives in such manner.
Appreciate any explanation, thank you.

Comment: Differentiating $k$ times and then differentiating $j-k$ times is the same as differentiating $k+(j-k)=j$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define higher-order derivatives recursively as $\dfrac{d^k f}{dx^k} = \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{d^{k - 1}f}{dx^{k - 1}}$. So, $\dfrac{d^{j - k}}{dx^{j - k}}\dfrac{d^k}{dx^k} f= \dfrac{d^j f}{dx^j}$

Also, $\dfrac{d^k}{dx^k} x^k = k!$ (Check)